# Blazor WebAssembly .NET 5 template in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, blazor

How can I update my Visual Studio Blazor WASM template so the newly created project uses .NET 5? When I create a Blazor WebAssembly project now it is set to .NET Core 3.1 for Server and .NET Standard 2.1 for client?

New template I guess would also have the changes already implemented that was needed to upgrade from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5.

Comment: If you upgrade to the latest VS 2019 version and/or .NET 5 SDK you get the latest version. *Converting existing projects* is a different thing. You could just change the target runtime in the csproj file after all. The important changes are those to your existing code. In .NET 5 you can *delete* quite a few `StateHasChanged` calls for example

Comment: Thats what I did, I updated VS to latest version and the SDK but the newly created project states .NET Core 3.1 and .NET Standard 2.1

Comment: Doesn't the dropdown show .net5 at all?

Comment: Well, that's odd. I'm running VS 16.8.5 and cannot reproduce this. When I add a "Blazor app" it's set to .NET 5.0 by default... I have no option for .NET standard 2.1.. But you said you have the latest SDK... do you have the [latest .NET 5.0 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0)? Just to be sure, do a `dotnet --list-sdks` in the package manager

Comment: To confirm above, I've just creating some new projects for an article and all setup for Net5. Blazor Server, Blazor WASM and standard Razor.  What Visual Studio Version are you running?  Check that it's 16.8.5 as @JHBonarius stated.  I'm on the same version  having update 2 days ago.  For updating from 3.1 to 5 see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI See the attached screenshot which shows the current Template for Blazor - I ran this this morning on VS 2019 Community 16.8.5.

Note the dropdown at the top for Net5.0 and the Template No in the bottom corner 5.0.3.

Also:

1. Make sure you have 5.0.3 version of DotNetCore installed
2. You are running 16.8.5 Visual Studio

[image: Blazor Template]

[image: DotNet Version]

[image: VS 2019 version]